ONNXRuntimeError for exported torchvision / fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_fpn
I get an ONNXRuntimeError when running FasterRCNN model exported to .onnx
Error:
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.RuntimeException: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 6 : RUNTIME_EXCEPTION : Non-zero status code returned while running Reshape node. Name:'/roi_heads/Reshape_2' Status Message: /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/providers/cpu/tensor/reshape_helper.h:39 onnxruntime::ReshapeHelper::ReshapeHelper(const onnxruntime::TensorShape&, onnxruntime::TensorShapeVector&, bool) size != 0 && (input_shape_size % size) == 0 was false. The input tensor cannot be reshaped to the requested shape. Input shape:{490,363}, requested shape:{-1,4}
Versions
onnxruntime 1.18.1
torch 2.2.2
torchvision 0.17.2
Here is a minimal reproductible example:
obs: The error shows up only in the cropped image. If I comment out img = img[50:200, 150:250] - it works fine.
import torch
import torchvision
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np
import onnxruntime

print("Exporting model")
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_fpn(weights='DEFAULT')
torch.onnx.export(model, torch.rand(1, 3, 640, 640), '/tmp/model.onnx', 
                    input_names=['input'], output_names=['boxes', 'scores', 'labels'])


print("Downloading image")
r = requests.get('https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/roi.jpg', allow_redirects=True)
open('/tmp/roi.jpg', 'wb').write(r.content)
img = cv2.imread('/tmp/roi.jpg')

img = img[50:200, 150:250]
cv2.imwrite('/tmp/roi2.jpg', img)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_dim_dim = cv2.resize(img, (640, 640))
image_dim_dim = np.array(image_dim_dim, dtype=np.float32) / 255.0
image_bchw = np.transpose(np.expand_dims(image_dim_dim, 0), (0, 3, 1, 2))

print("Running inference")
session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('/tmp/model.onnx', providers=["CPUExecutionProvider"])
outputs = [o.name for o in session.get_outputs()]
inputs = [o.name for o in session.get_inputs()]
prediction = session.run(outputs, {inputs[0]: image_bchw})
print(prediction)

